# emmet expression can't expanded in .vm file when use vs code

Tags: velocity, visual-studio-code, emmet

I change my editor to vs code recently and then setup a lot of plugins. I use velocity(.vm) in our project but use `emmet` to expand expression in a vm file with vs code.

It doesn't work and I try to slove it and find the source option file:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\node_modules\emmet\lib\snippets.json`

Then add this in the bottom `json`

```
"vm": {
  "filters": "vm",
  "extends": "html",
  "profile": "xml"
}
```

But it doesn't work too. So, I will ask that how do you solve this problem in your project module file (like `.ejs` `.php`...)?
Or if find the wrong place to modify the code ?

My Environment is: win 10 vs code 1.4.0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

`filter` is a name of a special JS method that formats expanded abbreviation. It had nothing with a document syntax. In your case, you have to find out how VS detects syntax for `.vm` files and then ensure that this syntax is supported by Emmet. E.g. the name of the syntax might be “velocity”